# Node:Link token in views

Tags: 7, views, tokens

I want to change the text shown for the Node:Link field, which by default is "View". How can I change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the the text in view, in the settings of the field "Node:link"

[image: https://img.skitch.com/20110407-kdwj5uf1762rk1a6cn8fqm6dmk.jpg]

Comment: *Hastily deletes his answer* :)